# scroll view does not display the received data correspondingly

Tags: android, scrollview

in my App i have a `scroll view` that should display data received from network `broker` using `mqtt` protocol at very high rate. the published DATA to the network `broker` are sent in millisecond percision. the time stamp spans from .001xx seconds to 4500 seconds, and for each time-scheduled some data will be published according to the time stamp, and the app should receive these data and display it on the `scroll view`.

the problem is, when the data is published at very high rate, the `scroll view` freez for some seconds then display the data, in other words, the `scroll view` does not display the data interactively.

to clarify my problem mre, i have a large file with thousands of lines, and each line has a time-stamp, and according to the time stamp i am publishing data from a java `GUI`, the published data is received on an Android App, that should display these data in the `scrolView`, but what happens is, for an example, after approx. 1000 published line, the `scroll view` display them at once, and for the subsequent 1000 lines the scroll view freez for a while and then display them at once, and it does not correspondingly display each published data, it should wait for a while then display bunch of published data.

is there any way to solve such problem.
i wish my explanation is clear.

**Code**:

```
sv_arrivedMessaes = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.sv_arrivedMessaes);
sv_arrivedMessaes.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv_msg_arrived.setText(mStrBuf);
                sv_arrivedMessaes.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You may get better help if you can add a code snippet showing how you are updating the data structure that scrollview is using. Also if the data is updating so quickly how do you expect a user to interact with it?

Comment: @hardillb Thank you, the scroll view is jus o display the published data, and at this point, the user should not interact with it, it is just display to the user